# Show that $2^n < n!$ for every positive integer $n$ with $n\geq 4$.

Tags: induction

Using Mathematical induction prove the above proposition.

Basis step can be verified easily. But how can i show that it is true for $p(n+1)$.

Comment: How do you get from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}$? What about from $n!$ to $(n+1)!$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247335/prove-formally-that-log-2-n-ge-n-for-all-integers-n3

Comment: You could see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409609/how-to-prove-4n2n2-for-n-geq-4-with-induction?rq=1 and divide by 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2^{n+1}=2*2^n\\\le2*n!\le(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, for induction, you usually end up proving the $n=1$ (or in this case $n=4$) case first. You've got that done.

Then you need to identify your inductive hypothesis:
e.g.

$$    n!>2^n$$

and

$$    n\ge 4$$

In class the proof might look something like this:

$$(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$$

from the inductive hypothesis we have

$$    n!(n+1)>2^n(n+1)$$

since

$$n>1$$

we have

$$    2^n(n+1)>2^n\cdot 2$$

and

$$    2^n\cdot 2=2^{n+1}$$

Now, we can string it all togther to get the inequality:

$$    (n+1)!=n!(n+1)>2^n(n+1)>2^n\cdot 2=2^{n+1}$$

$$    (n+1)!>2^{n+1}$$

In general, it's worth trying to figure out wether it 'safe'
to multiply

$$    n!>2^n$$

by

$$    n+1>2$$

while preserving the inequality.